# PHP include com problema nos caracteres

Tags: php, include

Estou utilizando o include em dois arquivos.

Um arquivo inclui normalmente, porém, o outro vem com problemas nos caracteres aparece nos acentos o caractere "�".

Mas abrindo os dois arquivos no `notepad++`, eles estão normais, com os acentos e tudo o mais.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Verifique o encode do arquivo que está abrindo errado. Salve como UTF-8 que deve funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque no COLLATE da base de dados utf8_unicode_ci

No script de conexão a base de dados colocas isto

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

E na pagina setas o CHARSET que estás a utilizador

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Se nada disso funcionar

```
echo utf8_encode(  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Abra os arquivos no notepad++ e vá no botão menu formatar e selecione a opção: Codificação em UTF-8 (sem BOM), veja que durante este processo pode haver uma mudança de carácter no arquivo .php (ex: mudando a letra `t` para `�`ou outro carácter estranho) logo você deverá mudar este carácter estranho pelo carácter correto.